# Getting below line when i am running application, unable to recognize is this related to show_SQL related or any error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

> Hibernate: select errorcode0_.CODE as CODE1_11_, errorcode0_.CODE_DESC
>   as CODE_DES2_11_, errorcode0_.CODE_TYPE as CODE_TYP3_11_,
>   errorcode0_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_4_11_, errorcode0_.CREATED_DATE as
>   CREATED_5_11_, errorcode0_.UPDATED_BY as UPDATED_6_11_,
>   errorcode0_.UPDATED_DATE as UPDATED_7_11_ from EXCEPTIONS errorcode0_
>   where errorcode0_.CODE_TYPE=?

Comment: It's related to `show_sql`.  This is the `SQL` `Hibernate` is executing.

Comment: You are right, this is due to show_SQl, not an error